# SQL substring start from backward

Tags: sql-server

can substring in sql server start from behind.The substr from oracle can do that.From what i know for if the code is like this `substring('Hello everybody',-4)` it will return 'body'.Does substring sql server have the same function?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `RIGHT` function:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(50) 
SET @x = 'Hello There'

SELECT RIGHT(@x, 5)   --'There'
```

Answer (score 0):

the use of `substring` function in SQL is `substring(string, start position, #of items)`

So in your case you can get the last 4 letters of the string via using;

```
substring('Hello everybody',-4,4)
```